# Creating new javascript Object form existing one

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, object, underscore.js

I have my original objects as follow. All I need is to just extract few properties from existing one and create new object.

```
var data = [{
    id: 3,
    name: Axe,
    location: alkt
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: Roy,
    location: grelad
}]
```

I need my output as,

```
var data_new = [{
    id: 3,
    name: Axe
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: Roy,
}]
```

How to implement in underscore js or any simple method. Possible its a large JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are just few properties you want to extract then simple [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will works fine:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Axe',
    location: 'alkt'
}, {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Roy',
    location: 'grelad'
}]

var result = data.map(function(obj) {
    return {
      id: obj.id,
      name: obj.name
    };
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: It has to be noted that this will not work in IE8 as it does not support `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: Yes, if IE8 is supported then `data.map(function(obj) {})` should be changed to `_.map(data, function(obj) {})`. Thanks for the note!

Comment: So you suggest if a browser only supports ECMA-Script 3 to use a full-blown library? I mean, we all love underscore.js, but why not just go with a standard approach of a `for` loop using `for..in` inside?

Comment: I assume that OP is already using underscore, so why not use it if IE8 support is necessary. If IE8 is not important then use ES5 map.

Answer (score 2):

Use **pick** in undescorejs http://underscorejs.org/#pick
Or **omit** http://underscorejs.org/#omit

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {
  return _.isNumber(value);
});
=> {age: 50}
```

Answer (score 1):

It you want remove each item's location

```
var data_new = _.map(data, function(item) {
  return _.omit(item, 'location');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is remove properties from objects in an array, you could just [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) them while iterating with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var data_new = data;
data_new.forEach(function(obj){ delete obj.location; /* or any other */ });
```

Comment: `forEach` is not supported in IE8. Also, OP is asking for a *new object*, not how to alter the original one.

Comment: There was no premise it had to work in a 4½ year old IE. My link even comprises a polyfill at MDN. An edited copy of the original object ''is'' a new object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data_new = [];
for(i in $scope.data){
  $scope.data_new.push(
   { id: $scope.data[i].id, name: $scope.data[i].name }
  )
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend not to use `for ... in` for arrays.