# lodash create new json object from existing one

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

I want to delete and rename some props of my existing JSON Object to use it with select2/select2 query plugins 
My JSON object that i need to transform is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Subject1",
    "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "sub1",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "tagType": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "Subject2",
    "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "id": 16,
        "name": "sub2",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "tagType": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "type": "Subject3",
    "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
    "Tags": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "sub3",
        "createdAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2016-02-19T23:03:12.000Z",
        "tagType": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To

```
[
  {
    "text": "Subject1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "sub1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Subject2",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 16,
        "text": "sub2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Subject3",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "text": "sub3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to :

1. rename name and type to text
2. delete tagType, updatedAt and createdAt
3. rename Tags to children
4. remove the id of each top objects

Is there a way to do all this using lodash ? 
What the best way?

Comment: tried with for loops and this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263886/creating-new-javascript-object-form-existing-one) but i didn't succeed in renaming the existing props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = _.map(items, function(item){
    return {
       text: item.type,
       children: _.map(item.Tags, function(tag){
           return {
               id: tag.id,
               text: tag.name
           };
       })
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I succed using this link by nesting two return : 
[Creating new javascript Object form existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263886/creating-new-javascript-object-form-existing-one)

```
 var result = tags.map(function(obj) {
                return {
                    text: obj.type,
                    childrens:obj.Tags.map(function(obj) {
                        return {
                            id : obj.id,
                            text : obj.name
                        }
                    })
                };
            });
```